# Convert Pyton Request call to PHP (cURL)

Tags: python, php

I am pulling my hair out :)

THe company I am using has a API I need to use but only gives an example to me in  Python.

Can someone help me convert it to PHP? I have tried several times but no luck. I think the problem is in the file sending.

Here is the Py code:

```
import requests
import json

def send_excel_catalog_import(fname, auth_token, report_recipient_email):

api_url = f"https://www.etailpet.com/COMPANY/api/v1/catalog-update/"

payload = {"email": report_recipient_email}

files = [
    ("product_import", open(fname, "rb"))
]

headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {auth_token}"}

response = requests.request(
    "POST", api_url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files
)

results_str = response.content.decode("utf8")
return response.status_code, json.loads(results_str)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    fname = "product_import.xlsx"
    send_excel_catalog_import(fname)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

function send_excel_catalog_import($fname, $auth_token, $report_recipient_email) {
    $api_url = "https://www.etailpet.com/COMPANY/api/v1/catalog-update/";
    $payload = array("email" => $report_recipient_email);
    $files = array(
        "product_import" => new CURLFile($fname)
    );
    $headers = array("Authorization: Bearer $auth_token");

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array_merge($payload, $files));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    curl_close($ch);

    return array($status_code, json_decode($response, true));
}

// Usage example
$fname = "product_import.xlsx";
$auth_token = "your_auth_token_here";
$report_recipient_email = "recipient@example.com";

list($status_code, $results) = send_excel_catalog_import($fname, $auth_token, $report_recipient_email);

echo "Status Code: $status_code\n";
echo "Results: " . print_r($results, true) . "\n";
?>
```

Make sure to replace "your_auth_token_here" with your actual authorization token. Also, ensure that the path to the file product_import.xlsx is correct.

Comment: Bro, it appears that the answer is generated from AI (I tested by typing "please convert the following code from python to PHP" and then provided the code, the result is more than 95% similar to yours). In my understanding it is not permitted to do it ?